# Bus Error 10 - Node Won't Start

Tags: baker

Lightning struck and I may have just lost my baker - Can't start my node, due to Bus Error 10

```
Apr 19 21:50:12 - validator.chain(1): Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa
Bus error: 10
```

Then stops. When lightning hit, everything shut off -- and now my node just says Bus Error 10. I copied the chain data to another pc and it says the same thing over there, too!